# Библиотеки для логгирования на си

Tags: c, логирование, linux

Есть надобность в библитеке для логирования, не просто вывод сообщений в файлик, а чтоб поддерживался следующий функционал, вывод сообщений с разных уровней, debug, profile, error, trace. так же поддерживался вывод сообщений в tty, сокет. Пока нашел только log4c, надеюсь на вашу помощь в поиске решений. Спасибо

Comment: А чем он плох? Использовал, был удовлетворен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А смотрели ли стандартный syslog? Он точно умеет и в файл, и по сети передать, и имеет разные уровни логгирования. И ротация логов. Умеет и в консоль выводить.
Также эта система логгированния привычна пользователям и администраторам. Многие вопросы просто не будут возникать.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо ничего усложнять без необходимости.

```
man -S 3 syslog
```

Это стандартные функции в любой Unix-системы, которые позволяют помещать записи в системный журнал. Ими и надо пользоваться при разработке прикладной программы. А уже системный администратор может настроить конкретное поведение локального и/или сетевого журнала.

Ротация журнала, разделение по категорям, сетевая поддержка и прочее, реализуется на уровне демона журнала (например, `syslogd`), который получает сообщения от функций стандартной библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Это все умеет стандартный syslog, еще есть syslog-ng.. 
Если машин очень много и хочется изюминки, можно поставить [graylog2](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/sysadm/132116/)